# Чат-бот подробно опишите на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, бот, чат

В прошлом вопросе я уже спрашивал, но мне ответили **очень кратко**.
Пожалуйста, напишите подробно и развёрнуто про чат-ботов и про то как их использовать, настраивать.

Comment: для чего нужен чат бот? локальный или в соц сети?

Comment: [Как задать хороший вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Egr вы ведь понимаете, что оскорбительные комментарии в любом случае будут удалены, а ответа на свой вопрос вы так и не получите?

Comment: @Egr это как раз тот случай, когда один дурак может задать такой вопрос, на который и что мудрецов не смогут ответить. Потому что хрен знает,что он спросить. Бери учебник и читай. Тут не детский сад.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 realtext = input() // ввод текста      
 realtext = event.text.lower() // Весь регистр в нижний
 realtext = realtext.replace('?', '')
 realtext = realtext.replace('!', '') // убираем знаки
 if realtext == 'ты лопух': 
 (print('Нет ты лопух') )
```

я новичок но должно работать.